# Blue screen IRQL while installing NVIDIA CUDA, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I've been messing around all day over my PC installing many development packages, at one time I installed CUDA 7.0 but then I realized that it was not compatible with some other tools I'd had to install, so I "down"dated it downloading the 5.5 version.

After finishing my 5.5 installation the setup asked for a reinitialization just like with 7.0 and when I came back after the welcome window when I type my password etc I got this blue screen with IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL issue. I tried to uninstall all the NVIDIA devices I could in safe mode to see if I could reboot my PC normally but there are some that I cannot.

I already tried the "last valid configuration" boot with <kbd>F8</kbd> and got the same blue screen after a pop-up saying that a file called NVI2.DLL was missing. I'd say that the PC is still trying to finish the installation of CUDA 5.5 at each boot, but fails miserably.

Any tips?

Update: The problem was installing CUDA 7.0 and 5.5 after that, I've made a system recovery for a date when 7.0 wasn't installed and 5.5 worked well

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to have been conflicts between installing CUDA 7.0 and 5.5 on top of one another, probably corrupting some driver components and registry settings in the process. A system recovery for a date when 7.0 wasn't installed and 5.5 worked well at restoring the system to a functional state.